# How to present SFSafariViewController in UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, webkit, sfsafariviewcontroller

i have a custom UIView that has a button property, i want to add an action to it to open webview in-app. To do that i want to use SFSafariViewController. Here is how i am trying to achieve this.

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class CustomViewScreen: UIView, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {

@IBAction func privacyNoteBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        let urlString = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url, entersReaderIfAvailable: true)
            vc.delegate = self
           UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}

func safariViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: SFSafariViewController) { 
  controller .dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) // also not able to trigger this method when i tap "Done"
}
```

I cant even propery use this way , since i am getting " whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" Also i am not able to call SFSafariViewControllerDelegate method to dismiss the view after tap "Done" button. Any idea to give action while i am in the UIView or any idea to connect this action to my main controller to use properly present method?

Comment: you can only present view controller on another view controller......you can't present view controller in view...instead you can add subview of other view controller...

Comment: what happend `self.present(`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this,

```
@IBAction func privacyNoteBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
   if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    let urlString = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url, entersReaderIfAvailable: true)
        vc.delegate = self

       if var topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
          while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
              topController = presentedViewController
          }

          topController.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }

    }
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: "https://apple.com")!)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addViewControllerAsChildViewController()
    }
    
    //firstVCIdentifier
    
    func addViewControllerAsChildViewController() {
        addChild(safariVC)
        self.view.addSubview(safariVC.view)
        safariVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        self.setUpConstraints()
    }
    
    func setUpConstraints() {
        self.safariVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.safariVC.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        self.safariVC.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true
        self.safariVC.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        self.safariVC.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. UIView can't present a viewcontroller, because they are different. You only can present a viewcontroller in a viewcontroller.

So I suggest your view just get touch event, and delegate to viewcontroller , tell it to present a SFSafariViewController. Like this:

```
// view.h
@protocol AccountBindingDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)jumpWebVC:(UIButton*)sender;
@end
@interface CustomRegisterView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<AccountBindingDelegate> delegate;
@end

// view.m
[agreementBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(agreementBtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)agreementBtnClick:(UIButton*)sender
{
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(jumpWebVC:)]) {
        [self.delegate jumpWebVC:sender];
    }
}

// code in controller
@interface uiviewContrller ()<AccountBindingDelegate> 

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    _registerView.delegate = self;
}

//tell viewcontroller to present
- (void)jumpWebVC:(UIButton*)sender
{
    PSMFWebVC *webVC = [PSMFWebVC new];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webVC animated:YES];
}
```

UIView don't need know the url, he just tell the viewcontroller : some button in uiview had been click. In case, your uivew has lots of buttons , your CustomViewScreen will be heavy which is not good.

Answer (score 0):

I am put here open SafariViewController on the UIViewController for share of the knowledge. My target was open SafariViewController in-app. If you want you can customize it with adding subviews of different constraints.

> MainVC trigger point.

```
    let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: "yourLink")
    let vc = PresentVC(safariVC: safariVC)
    present(vc, animated: true)
```

> PresentVC

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class PresentVC: UIViewController {

private var safariVC: SFSafariViewController

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addChild(safariVC)
    self.view.addSubview(safariVC.view)
    self.safariVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    self.safariVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.safariVC.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    self.safariVC.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    self.safariVC.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    self.safariVC.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
}

init(safariVC: SFSafariViewController) {
    self.safariVC = safariVC
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```